# onBackPressed(); doesn't work unless I call super.onBackPressed(); twice in code

Tags: java, android

I am having trouble with the `onBackPressed();` method. I need the icons of the `BottomNavView` to change depending on what `Fragment` the user lands on calling `onBackPressed();`. That isn't happening right now with the code that I currently have. I've tried several different ways to implement this code, but nothing has worked. So the two biggest outcomes I am getting is if I call `super.onBackPressed();` twice the `BNV icons` change, BUT the images in one of my `Fragments` come back duplicated and I don't know why...

So if I get rid of one of the `onBackPressed();` the BNV icons just straight up don't change with `onBackPressed();`

I was thinking that maybe I should change the `instanceOf in onBackPressed();` to `polymorphism`... I have seen that that is something that people have done instead of `instanceOf`… I don't know if that will solve my problem. Could someone let me know what they think?

Is there maybe a `onBackPressedListener or fragmentListener` that I could implement to make this code work?

The strangest thing is that the images come back doubled for only ONE of my fragments... All the others are okay.

**MainActivity**

```
private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener navigationItemSelectedListener = menuItem -> {
        switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.nav_home:
                mSelectedFragment = new TabLayoutFragment();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_notifications:
                seenNotification();
                mSelectedFragment = new NotificationsFragment();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_profile:
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("PREFS", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                editor.putString("profileid", mFirebaseUser.getUid());
                editor.apply();
                mSelectedFragment = new ProfileFragment();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_save:
                mSelectedFragment = new AttendingEventFragment();
                break;
        }

        if (mSelectedFragment != null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, mSelectedFragment, null).addToBackStack(null).commit();
        }

        return true;
    };

     @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (mDrawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            mDrawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }

        Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);
        if (fragment instanceof TabLayoutFragment) {
            mBottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.nav_home);
        } else if (fragment instanceof AttendingEventFragment) {
            mBottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.nav_save);
        } else if (fragment instanceof NotificationsFragment) {
            mBottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.nav_notifications);
        } else if (fragment instanceof ProfileFragment) {
            mBottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.nav_profile);
        }
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
```

**EventFragment** THIS IS THE ONE WHERE THE IMAGES ARE COMING BACK DOUBLED. ONLY ONE WHERE IT HAPPENS...

```
public class AttendingEventFragment extends Fragment implements SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener {

    private List<String> mEvent;
    private List<Post> mPostList;

    private String mPostId;

    private EventsImagesAdapter mEventsImagesAdapter;
    private FirebaseUser mFirebaseUser;

    private TextView mNoEvents;
    private ImageView mBackArrow;

    private SwipeRefreshLayout mSwipeRefreshLayout;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_attending_event, container, false);

        mFirebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

        mNoEvents = view.findViewById(R.id.no_events);

        mBackArrow = view.findViewById(R.id.arrow_back);

        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getContext().getSharedPreferences("PREFS", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        mPostId = sharedPreferences.getString("postid", "none");

        RecyclerView recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getContext(), 3);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        mPostList = new ArrayList<>();
        mEventsImagesAdapter = new EventsImagesAdapter(getContext(), mPostList);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(mEventsImagesAdapter);

        ((DrawerLocker) getActivity()).setDrawerLocked(true);

        mSwipeRefreshLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.refresh);
        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(this);
        mSwipeRefreshLayout.post(() -> {
            mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
            mySaves();
        });

        setBackArrow();

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        ((DrawerLocker) getActivity()).setDrawerLocked(false);
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    private void mySaves() {
        mEvent = new ArrayList<>();
        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Attending Event");
        reference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    if (snapshot.hasChild(mFirebaseUser.getUid()))
                        mEvent.add(snapshot.getKey());
                }

                Log.d("READSAVES", String.valueOf(mEvent));
                readSaves();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }

    private void readSaves() {
        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Posts");
        reference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                mPostList.clear();
                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Post post = snapshot.getValue(Post.class);
                    for (String id : mEvent) {
                        if (post != null)
                            if (post.getPostid().equals(id)) {
                                mPostList.add(post);
                            }
                    }
                }

                Log.d("SAVES", mPostList.toString());

                if (mPostList.size() == 0) {
                    mNoEvents.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                } else {
                    mNoEvents.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }

                mEventsImagesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                Collections.reverse(mPostList);
                mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);

            }
        });
    }

    private void setBackArrow() {
        mBackArrow.setOnClickListener(v -> getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack());
    }

    @Override
    public void onRefresh() {
        mySaves();
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you getting the right fragment by `findFragmentById` ?

Comment: @ADM well that's the container that I have for the fragments in my MainActivity. But yeah, that one is good. It's only one of the four fragments that the images are coming back doubled always... All the others are fine. I have no idea why...

Answer (score 1):

`super.onBackPressed()` will call the desired behavior of back press . And you are calling twice in your code. your code should look like below .

```
@Override
        public void onBackPressed () {
            if (mDrawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
                mDrawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                return;
            }
            super.onBackPressed();
            Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);
            if (fragment instanceof TabLayoutFragment) {
                mBottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.nav_home);
            } else if (fragment instanceof AttendingEventFragment) {
                mBottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.nav_save);
            } else if (fragment instanceof NotificationsFragment) {
                mBottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.nav_notifications);
            } else if (fragment instanceof ProfileFragment) {
                mBottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.nav_profile);
            }
        }
```

Now if you get the correct fragment from stack by `#findFragmentById` it should work .

Comment: This ALMOST works, but here the problem is it only goes back one fragment. Let's say I have Home, Notifications, and Profile and I have been switching between them for a while. Regardless, when I hit the back button it only goes back one fragment... And then if I keep clicking it, it just keeps reloading the fragment I am currently on.

Comment: Thats the desired behavior of back press it will pop fragment Stack once only for an action . If you want to Change this you should Consider doing this by code. have a look at [this article](https://medium.com/@bherbst/managing-the-fragment-back-stack-373e87e4ff62) .

Comment: I think I already do that though, addToBackStack(null)… I do that for all fragment transactions to have it in the stack. I just uploaded the code I use to change between fragments. You mind taking a look and telling me if that's what you mean, or if something needs to be added?

Comment: Actually yeah, I'm pretty sure that's what you meant...

Comment: You have any other suggestions? I legit have been working on this problem for more than a month and I don't know what to do... Maybe we can chat or something?